# Matrices of complex numbers multiplication

Tags: matrix, c, complex

I'm trying to implement the multiplication of two matrices something like this picture in c langage. [image]

I want to read the numbers from a text file of x and store it later in an array the code that i tried is below
So the problem that I have is when i use the  static method `Complex x[4] = { { 1,0 },{ 0,-1 },{ 1,1 },{ 4,-1 } };` **it's work** but when i want to read it from **input.txt** `Complex x[4]` it does not work what i missed.

```
typedef struct Complex
{
    double real;
    double image;
}Complex;

int main()
{
   Complex x[4] = { { 1,0 },{ 0,-1 },{ 1,1 },{ 4,-1 } };
   Complex y[4] = { { 0,1 },{ 1,-1 },{ 2,-3 },{ 4,0 } };
   FILE *input;
   input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
   if (sensorInput == NULL ) {
        printf(stderr, "Cannot open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i<4; ++i)
        {
                fscanf(sensorInput, "%lf + j*%lf\t", &x[i]); 
                printf("\n");
        }
    }

}
```

input.txt
1,0
0,-1
1,1
4,-1

Comment: There are matrix manipulation packages for C, C++, FORTRAN, Python and Rust -- and those are just the ones that I know about.  They handle input/output, math, linear algebra, etc., etc..

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
                fscanf(sensorInput, "%lf + j*%lf\t", &x[i]);
```

should be

```
                fscanf(sensorInput, "%lf,%lf\t", &x[i].real, &x[i].imag);
```

Notice that C++ provides [complex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_ltltgtgt) type, they support the common complex operations, and provide an io, and they can read complex numbers writen as `(1,3)` directly `file_in >> x[i]`, once you have a [istream](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/)

Note that this type of question you should ask in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead.